# kendo ui mobile data-icon not showing image

Tags: html, mobile, kendo-ui

this is my code.

```
<div data-role="layout" data-id="main-layout">`enter code here`
    <div data-role="footer"> <div data-role="tabstrip"><a data-icon="home" href="#home">Home</a>
```

Settings

here data-icon is not working. i mean data-icon is not showing property is not showing any image. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which version of Kendo UI Mobile are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/mobile/icons#custom-icons-in-wp8) may be of assistance.  It goes into great detail about using font icons in mobile apps which is what you are doing.  I don't know what mobile device, if any, you are testing on but the article states that they do not work on Window Phone 8.  They DO appear to work just fine in IE11 desktop when emulating WP8 via the developer tools.  For WM8 you have to use regular old image icons rather that font icons.  Again, this is according to the article.  I have not tested on a WP8 device myself.